# How to use financial functions in google appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I use finacial functions available in google sheets such as [FV](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093224) in my custom google appscript function?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Google Sheets file where you want to create the custom function.
2. Click on "Extensions" in the menu bar and select "Apps Script" to open the Apps Script editor.
3. In the Apps Script editor, write your custom function using the built-in SpreadsheetApp service.
4. Save the script and return to your spreadsheet.
5. Now you can use your custom function customFV in any cell of your spreadsheet by typing =customFV(rate, nper, pmt, pv) and providing the appropriate arguments.